# Key binding for Eclipse commands

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to bind the *Toggle Breakpoint* command, `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.ToggleBreakpoint`, to <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

I extended `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` in this way:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <scheme
        description="Default scheme for xvr"
        id="org.xvr.scheme"
        name="xvr.scheme"
        parentId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
  </scheme>
  <key
        commandId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.ToggleBreakpoint"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        schemeId="org.xvr.scheme"
        sequence="F9">
  </key>
```

But when I launch my RCP application nothing happens if I press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I'm developing a new product from eclipse and I can't use the preference window of eclipse.

I have to provide a binding through   org.eclipse.ui.bindings extension point.

**EDIT2**

Thanks to Paul, using tracing I saw that an exception is thrown when I press <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
COMMANDS >>> execute >>> starting: id=org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.ToggleBreakpoint; event=ExecutionEvent(Command(org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.ToggleBreakpoint,Toggle Breakpoint,
        Creates or removes a breakpoint,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        ,
        ,,true),{},Event {type=1 StyledText {} time=25349140 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=0},org.eclipse.core.expressions.EvaluationContext@ffa7e1)
COMMANDS >>> execute >>> not handled: id=org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.ToggleBreakpoint; exception=org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.ToggleBreakpoint
```

Comment: Is there anything in your error log?  `<workspace>/.metadata/.log` or you can add -consoleLog to your launch arguments.  You can also set some tracing options to see what happens when you press F9 - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Tracing_Option

Comment: Thanks Paul!using tracing options i saw that an exception is thrown..more on edit

Comment: That means nothing is providing an implementation for that command in your RCP.  Run the tracing in your eclipse and you'll get an idea of what is doing the work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the following to plugin.xml, where **defaultHandler**  is a class extending *AbstractHandler* and overridding *execute()*

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command name="Remove All Comments"
        defaultHandler="commentremover.actions.CommentRemover"
        description="Removes all comments in source code"
        categoryId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.source"
        id="commentremover.removeallcomments">
   </command>
</extension>
```

Also, you need to add the following, where **commandId** equals the **id** of the command you defined above

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
    <key sequence="Ctrl+Shift+D"
        commandId="commentremover.removeallcomments"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        contextId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorScope"/>
</extension>
```

The above is all I needed to get my plugin to work.  You will know it is working if it appears in the "Keys" preference menu.  It is a plugin that removes all comments in the source code when you press Ctrl+Shift+D.

Comment: This would be true if I had defined the command..no? ToggleBreakpoint is a command defined in org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.* and i would like to use that command. I successfully bind others commands from org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.* but not ToggleBreakpoint.

Comment: If you want to override the behavior of an existing command, I have done that before by shadowing an entire JDT package.  However, it is not guaranteed that your code will get run instead of the original.  Another way to do it is with a feature patch I  believe.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you go to

*Windows* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Keys*

and simply assign <kbd>F9</kbd> to the *Toggle Breakpoint* command.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but it is not the case. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which platform you're working on, but...

one some platforms - e.g. MacOS - the key assignment for <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, etc *cannot* be changed :-(

You can try that out inside a regular Eclipse as well from the Keys preference page.